# How to control a program running on linux PC using android application?

Tags: android, linux, android-wireless, wireless

I have a requirement where, I need to establish communication between a program running in Linux machine and android app running on phone. Both phone and PC are connected to same wireless network. I want to transfer data between app and linux process.

A simple use case can be, controlling a PC game from android device. I am looking for some standard solution for this kind of problem

Comment: Websockets? This is wildly broad.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to implement a Web Service on the machine you would like to control. This will make it so you don't have to invent your own protocol and deal with sockets, and it will give you a lot of control and ease compared to something like SSH.